# Is adding user time + system time (from the shell's time command) a reliable measure even when multitasking?

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I know user time deals with CPU time so it isn't affected by time-sharing, since it inly measures the number of CPU operations when our process had the CPU for itself. 
But can the system time be slowed down if like multiple process are doing I/O ?

Answer (score 0):

There are three measures which are easily available

1. wall time - how much time has elapsed.
2. kernel time - how much work the system did on your behalf
3. user time - how much time your code ran.

These help tell a story, but not a whole story.  In general the system accounts for these in a special way. it allows your program to run on a cpu core for a fixed length of time.

When that time elapses, it stops your program, and checks if there is anything else to do.  If there is nothing else, your program starts again.

The values of user and system time you get from the common operating systems (Windows, unix), are basically a count of the number of times the system reached the end of the quantum and found your program in user mode code (user time), or kernel code (kernel time).

Thus the time measured by the user/system, is an estimate of the time spent, not an accurate measurement.

If you perform I/O, or yield your quantum (e.g. calling `sleep`), then the system will not account for any of your time spent, and will assume you were idle for almost all of the quantum, and no time is accounted for you application (user or system).

The wall time is usually delivered by "reliable" timers.  They may not give accurate time-of-day (PCs can drift by seconds per day), but they will give an accurate measure of elapsed time - they will measure the number of clock-ticks which have occurred between two intervals, and that will be unaffected by load on the systems (VMs can be impacted by load on the machine).

> But can the system time be slowed down if like multiple process are doing I/O

The system time is stable, and (excluding VMs on a machine under load), will provide accurate and repeatable time measurements.

> I know user time deals with CPU time

User time (and kernel time), are guesses at how much time is spent by an application, and can be fooled.